# HTML document redirects me. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please observe that this question is on the topic of computer security and Cross Site Request forgery and that I have no intents other than to learn about these subjects.

Assuming a user has a current session at dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar, this code is intended by me to:

1. Transfer 1 zoobar from the users account to the other user "sahand".

I want this to be done in my document by:

1. Filling in the values of a form that is identical to the one found on dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/transfer.php. (I have copied this form to my document)
2. Submitting the values so that the transfer is made.

Here's the HTML document:

```
<form method="POST" name="transferform"
  action="http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/transfer.php">
<p>Send <input name=zoobars type=text value="1" size=5> </p>
<p>to <input name=recipient type=text value="sahand" size=10></p>
<input type=submit name=submission value="Send">
</form>
<script>
document.transferform.submit()
</script>
```

What happens when I open this document is that I am redirected to http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/transfer.php, and the form is filled in with the values I have provided in the HTML document. As far as I can see, no transfer has been made, since the amount of zoobars for the user is unchanged.

So what, I'm asking is, how can I get this document to achieve the desired functionality?

EDIT: PHP code for transfer.php:

```
<?php 
  require_once("includes/common.php"); 
  nav_start_outer("Transfer");
  nav_start_inner();
  if($_POST['submission']) {
    $recipient = $_POST['recipient'];
    $zoobars = (int) $_POST['zoobars'];
    $sql = "SELECT Zoobars FROM Person WHERE Username='" .
           addslashes($user->username) . "'";
    $rs = $db->executeQuery($sql);
    $sender_balance = $rs->getValueByNr(0,0) - $zoobars;

    $sql = "SELECT Username, Zoobars FROM Person WHERE Username='" .
       addslashes($recipient) . "'";
    $rs = $db->executeQuery($sql);
    $recipient_exists = $rs->getValueByNr(0,0);
    if($zoobars > 0 && $sender_balance >= 0 && $recipient_exists) {
      $sql = "UPDATE Person SET Zoobars = $sender_balance " .
             "WHERE Username='" . addslashes($user->username) . "'";
      $db->executeQuery($sql);
      $sql = "SELECT Zoobars FROM Person WHERE Username='".
             addslashes($recipient) . "'";
      $rs = $db->executeQuery($sql);
      $recipient_balance = $rs->getValueByNr(0,0) + $zoobars;
      $sql = "UPDATE Person SET Zoobars = $recipient_balance " .
             "WHERE Username='" . addslashes($recipient) . "'";
      $db->executeQuery($sql);
      $result = "Sent $zoobars zoobars";
    }
    else $result = "Transfer to $recipient failed.";
  }
?>
```

Comment: The post request probably does not have the cookie values that say you are logged in/ aka session info. (just a guess, did not look at that is happening)

Comment: "So what, I'm asking is, how can I get this document to achieve the desired functionality?" — First look at the code for `transfer.php` to find out what input it expects beyond what you have passed to it.

Comment: you tagged as PHP, so where is it?

Comment: `document.transferform.submit()` is automatically submitting the form when the page loads presumably passing the `POST` values of `zoobars=1&recipient=sahand`. Without seeing the associated PHP code, it's difficult to discern the issue.

Comment: I will add in the PHP code then.

Comment: you may also want to quote those name attributes. Some browsers don't like those being unquoted.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($db))` to `mysqli_query()` and look at your developer console.

Comment: I wonder what `nav_start_outer("Transfer");` and `nav_start_inner();` does

Comment: No idea Carlos, this isn't code written by me, it's code for the Zoobar website that is often used in computer security education.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if($_POST['submission']) {
> ```

The form tests to see if a piece of data named "submission" is in the data you send to the page.

> ```
> <input type=submit name=submission value="Send">
> ```

The only control you have with that name is a submit button.

If you submit the form using it, then it will be a successful control and be included in the form data.

> ```
>  document.transferform.submit()
> ```

You don't use the submit button to submit the form.

Consequently it isn't a successful control and isn't included in the data.

---

So you must either:

- Include name/value in the submitted data through a control that will be submitted
- Change the test in the PHP *or*
- Submit the form manually instead of with JS

Comment: Okay, thank you a lot for your response. Shouldn't there be a fourth alternative, where I use javascript to use the submit button to submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

Like Quentin said, the PHP code will look for the name "submission", which apparently will only be provided if one uses the button for submission. So I have done this, with a new command: `document.getElementsByName("submission")[0].click()`. This does the job. So the final HTML document looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" name="transferform"
  action="http://dasak.csc.kth.se/zoobar/transfer.php">
<p>Send <input name="zoobars" type=text value="1" size=5> </p>
<p>to <input name="recipient" type=text value="sahand" size=10></p>
<input type=submit name="submission" value="Send">
</form>
<script>
document.getElementsByName("submission")[0].click()
</script>
```